# Angular custom directive scope not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have a few directives being used on a page in my TypeScript application, and each have their own controllers to manage their own scope. Everything has been working quite smoothly until this really strange bug.

I have a `keypad` directive being used in a `payment` directive which is called by my `order` controller. I'm going to keep my code samples minimal for simplicity.

My `payment` directive has a controller which has a constructor that has:

```
$scope.vm = this;
```

I use this pattern very frequently. My `payment` directive also has a function `keypadOnChange()` that is invoked from the `keypad` directive.

```
// In the payment directive:
public keypadOnChange(keypadDirective: IKeypadDirectiveController): void {

    console.log("keypad is changed");
    console.log(keypadDirective.selection);

    this.manualTenderInputValue = Number(keypadDirective.selectionToString());

    console.log(this.manualTenderInputValue);

}
```

The thing worth noting here is that the `console` displays everything I expect it to at exactly the right time.

My template for the `payment` directive contains:

```
<div ng-show="vm.keypadIsVisible" class="square_keypad">

    <div class="white"
         keypad
         onchange="vm.keypadOnChange"></div>

    </div>

<div class="item manual-tender-input-field item-white item-small-padding"
        ng-click="vm.toggleKeypadVisibility()">

    {{ vm.manualTenderInputValue }}

</div>
```

Again, the thing worth noting is that all functions and behavior are working as expected -- including `vm.keypadIsVisible` which is changed in a similar way to `vm.manualTenderInputValue`.

The problem is that `vm.manualTenderInputValue` is not getting updated. It displays the appropriate value on page load, and I can `console.log()` its value when it's changed, and it is correct, but I can't get the `{{ }}` to update.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

---

### Update

My `keypad` directive handles a change event, so it can tell anyone listening about the change and they can do as they please with the data. It looks like this (and spoiler: here in lies the problem...)

My keypad directive has a controller that has these noteworthy lines:

```
// a public variable:
public onChange: any = null;

// in the constructor:
$scope.$watch("onchange", (v) => { this.onChange = v; });

// in a function invoked by ng-click:
public selectNumber(digit: string, domId?: string): void {
    // ... some other stuff not relevant ...
    this.triggerOnChange();
}

// the triggerOnChange in the keypad directive controller:
public triggerOnChange(): void {
    if (this.onChange) {
        this.onChange(this);
    }
}
```

Now, back to my `payment` which had a template that had a line looked like:

```
<div class="white"
     keypad
     onchange="vm.keypadOnChange"></div>
```

And the `payment` directive controller has the `keypadOnChange` function included in the original post. I threw in a `console.log(this)` and discovered that in *that* context, `this` was referring to the instance of the `keypad` directive controller. And that is the problem!

But... how do I fix *this*? (no pun intended)

**How do I make it so that when `keypadOnChange` is invoked on the `payment` controller it still has the right `this` context (and can therefore update the scope)?**

One final note, I'm using this `keypad` directive elsewhere and didn't run into this issue.

Comment: I am not sure. But try calling '$scope.$apply();' after updating manualTenderInputValue value in the directive.

Comment: What is onchange? what kind of binding is it? How are you triggering that function? Can you try to isolate the problem and replicate it in a demo.

Comment: PSL: The `console.log()`s were an attempt to indicate that things were being invoked as expected.

Comment: Mansi: I did try that and got an error saying that a digest was already in progress.

Comment: @amlyhamm How is it invoked, that matters when you want angular to update the bindings. I think you may need to provide more information or a simple replica of your issue. What is the definision of the directive, how the bindings are.. etc.. Question is unclear the way it is now.

Comment: Right you are, PSL. I'm adding more info now.

Comment: Shouldn't you use ng-change instead of onchange?

Comment: You're doing a lot of work that Angular is ready to take care of for you.  `$scope.vm = this;` in the controller ought to be an isolate scope in the directive instead (else you'll have scope collision problems when two directives try to share the controller.)  Instead of `$watch`ing an onchange handler, use `ng-change`.

Comment: That is a bit confusing -- this is a custom attribute that I happened to name `onchange `. The directive is using `ng-click`, which calls a `keypad` function, does some stuff, and then eventually calls the function specified in the `onchange` attribute.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/ Also a MCVE will make it easier to find a solution to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sander_P You cant just use ng-change on a div without specific implementation for it. also  **[`ng-change` requires](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L72)** `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was ensuring that I could maintain the `this` context for the `payment` directive controller.

---

My `payment` controller constructor ended up including:

```
this.keypadChange = this.onKeypadChange.bind(this);
```

While `onKeypadChange()` remained the same:

```
public keypadOnChange(keypadDirective: IKeypadDirectiveController): void {

    // is now referring to the instance of the controller, NOT the keypad directive:
    console.log(this);
    this.manualTenderInputValue = Number(keypadDirective.selectionToString());

 }
```

Finally, the template that calls the `keypad` directive now looks like:

```
<div class="white" keypad onchange="vm.keypadChange"></div>
```

---

*Based on comments and suggestions, I'll likely be changing some of my attribute names to avoid confusion, but this solution answers my original question.*